# How to discover what argument format must be used in a method?

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments, superclass

Currently working on a very simple Java project, however I've encountered a problem. I'm unsure as for what arguments I need to find a command, specified by the original Jar. Since, if it's possible, I would be using this in a number of situations, providing the exact files involved wouldn't be too useful. However, if someone could please explain how to find the format the arguments should be in for a method?

Example - `robot.ifBesideThing()`, and I'm unsure what to put in the (). I want to know how to find the possible arguments. I'm using Eclipse.

I've tried searching through guides and google, however keyword wise, I'm almost always led off to an unrelated problem.

Comment: Does the original jar come with documentation?

Comment: @JasonC Not that I can find.

Comment: What is this jar and where did it come from?

Comment: @JasonC I obtained it from another source, however I believe the original source is http://www.learningwithrobots.com/

Comment: All the documentation for the samples there is at http://www.learningwithrobots.com/software/software.html (specifically: http://www.learningwithrobots.com/doc/index.html). I just clicked "Software" on the left side. Does that not cover the jar you are using? [`Robot.isBesideThing()`](http://www.learningwithrobots.com/doc/becker/robots/Robot.html#isBesideThing(becker.robots.IPredicate))?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the original source code available: Look at it.

If the original jar came with documentation, or documentation is available: Read it.

If the original jar did not come with documentation: Request it from the original author.

If you are using Eclipse, and you add the jar to your build path: Eclipse will autocomplete parameters as you are typing; you could discover usage that way although if you do not know what the parameters *mean* (e.g. lack of documentation) it may not do you much good.

In the Eclipse case, if you do not know what packages or classes are available to you: Extract the jar and view the contents (they're just zip files, or use `jar x`), or if you know the name of one of the classes in it, use that class in Eclipse then press Ctrl+Shift+O to find the package it is in (Eclipse will add imports automatically or prompt you if there is ambiguity).

If you are desperate, you could hack together a method using reflection, but this would not tell you any more than Eclipse's autocomplete will tell you.

Comment: In the above comment I provided the source I most likely received the Jar from, and Eclipse's autocomplete only tells me `arg0`, which I can't understand as there are a number of arguments I could feed it, which all appear to be wrong.